# PDO cannot connect to MySql(Phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

hi so im really new at this stuff, so i try to explain very specific what my problem is and i did look into another questions on stackoverflow but it still doesnt fix my problem.

i follow some PHP Tutorial in youtube and testing it with xampp localhost. and everything is WORKING, No Error.

The problem is i want to upload this project online using my university Server. so what i did is i copy all the project and i changed  the database name,password,dbname etc.

the Teacher at youtube mentioned that he is using PDO to connect into my SQL. but after i copy all the project and testing it with my university server, it shows only blank page without telling me the error. so i dont know what is the problem here

so in order to connect to database he made 2 file, which is config.php and database.php

**here is the config.php code:**

```
<?php define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "name");
define("SITE_TITLE", "Easy Job"); ?>
```

**and here is the database.php code**

```
<?php 
class Database{
private $host = DB_HOST;
private $user = DB_USER;
private $pass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $error;
private $stmt;

public function __construct(){
  //Set DSN
  $dsn = 'mysql:host='. $this->host . ';dbname='. $this->dbname;

  //options
  $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  );

  // PDO Instance
  try {
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      $this->error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}

public function query($query){
  $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if(is_null($type)){
        switch(true){
            case is_int ( $value ) :
              $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
              break;

            case is_bool ( $value ) :
              $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
              break;

            case is_null ( $value ) :
              $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
              break;

            default :
              $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;

        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute(){
  return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultSet(){
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function single(){
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
} ?>
```

so once again my problem is after i copy all the file into the server, it just shows blank page without telling me what the error is.

thank you so much for your attention and your help.

Comment: First step is to turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: hi dave, im sorry but i am very new with php so i just follow exactly like the tutorial, my question is, where should i copy this all code? or i make a new .php file with this code? im sorry with the silly question:( and i appreciate so much with your answer.

Comment: Put it at the top of `index.php` or whatever PHP file you are calling that isn't working.

Comment: dave, thank you so much now i got where is the error message and i can fix the problem, i thank you once again for your help